# Passing a variable into ant

Tags: ant

If I pass a variable to ant by doing

```
ant -Dsomething=blah
```

How can I refer to it in my build.xml? I tried *@something@* and *${something}* but neither seem to work.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is set some properties (versions) at compile time.

*update*: the problem of course turned out to be somewhere else - accepting the most complete looking answer with examples

Comment: ${something} should work fine.  Can you post the section of your Ant build file where you are referring to the variable, plus the result of putting "<echo message="Value passed in = ${something}" /> in your build file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't you hate it when you over think these things:

```
<project name="test">
    <echo message="The value of foo is ${foo}"/>
</project>
```

Now, I'll run my program. Notice that I never defined a value for property `foo` in my `build.xml`. Instead, I'll get it from the command line:

```
$ ant -Dfoo=BAR_BAR_FOO

test:
     [echo] The value of foo is BAR_BAR_FOO

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 time: 0 seconds
```

See. Nothing special at all. You treat properties set on the command line just like normal properties.

Here's where the fun comes in. Notice that I've defined the property `foo` in my `build.xml` this time around:

```
<project name="test">
     <property name="foo" value="barfu"/>
     <echo message="The value of foo is ${foo}"/>
</project>
```

Now watch the fun:

```
$ ant
test:
     [echo] The value of foo is barfu

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 time: 0 seconds
```

Now, we'll set the property `foo` on the command line:

```
$ ant -Dfoo=BAR_BAR_FOO
test:
     [echo] The value of foo is BAR_BAR_FOO

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 time: 0 seconds
```

See the command line overrides the value I set in the `build.xml` file itself. This way, you can have defaults that can be overwritten by the command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do something like the following:

```
<mkdir dir="build/src"/>
<copy todir="build/src" overwrite="true">
  <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
  <filterset>
    <filter token="VERSION" value="${version}"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

...which will cause your source to get copied, replacing `@VERSION@`:

```
public class a { public static final String VERSION = "@VERSION@"; }
```

...and then include `build/src` in your `javac` src.

That said, I don't recommend this approach since the source copy step is expensive, and it will undoubtedly cause confusion.  In the past, I've stored a version.properties file in my package with `version=x.y`.  In my Java code, I used `Class.getResourceAsStream("version.properties")` and `java.util.Properties`.  In my build.xml, I used `<property file="my/pkg/version.properties"/>` so that I could create an `output-${version}.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

`${argsOne}` works for me and is easily referenced if the invoking command is

`ant -DargsOne=cmd_line_argument`

[Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline) also says so. This should work, try running with `ant -debug` and paste the output.